# How to scroll a LazyRow faster using the dpad?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I'm trying to implement a carousel component on Android TV with Compose, and I have a problem with fast scrolling using the dpad. NB: I want to keep the focused item as the first displayed item on the screen.

Here is a screen capture:

[image: Carousel screen capture]

The first 5 items are scrolled by pressing and releasing the right key after each item. The next 15 items are scrolled by keeping the right key pressed to the end of the list.

The scrolling and focus management work well, but I would like to make it faster. On the screen capture you see that when pressing the right key, the list is scrolled *then* the next item gets the focus. It is really slow.

Here is the Composable function:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun CustomLazyRow() {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyRow(
        state = scrollState,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(
            items = (1..20).toList()
        ) { index, item ->
            var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            Text(
                text = "Item $item",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .dpadNavigation(scrollState, index)
                    .width(156.dp)
                    .aspectRatio(4 / 3F)
                    .onFocusChanged { isFocused = it.isFocused }
                    .focusable()
                    .border(if (isFocused) 4.dp else Dp.Hairline, Color.Black)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And the `dpadNavigation` Modifier function:

```kotlin
fun Modifier.dpadNavigation(
    scrollState: LazyListState,
    index: Int
) = composed {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    var focusDirectionToMove by remember { mutableStateOf<FocusDirection?>(null) }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    onKeyEvent {
        if (it.type == KeyEventType.KeyDown) {
            when (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode) {
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT -> focusDirectionToMove = FocusDirection.Left
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT -> focusDirectionToMove = FocusDirection.Right
            }
            if (focusDirectionToMove != null) {
                scope.launch {
                    if (focusDirectionToMove == FocusDirection.Left && index > 0) {
                        // This does not work:
                        // scope.launch { scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index - 1) }
                        scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index - 1)
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Left)
                    }
                    if (focusDirectionToMove == FocusDirection.Right) {
                        // scope.launch { scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index + 1) }
                        scrollState.animateScrollToItem(index + 1)
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
```

I thought it was caused by the `animateScrollToItem` function that had to complete before executing `moveFocus`.

So I tried to execute `animateScrollToItem` in its own `launch` block but it didn't work; in this case there is no scrolling at all.

You can see the complete source code in a repo at https://github.com/geekarist/perf-carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Google is working on making Jetpack compose compatible with TV. Checkout [Android TV Compose releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/tv).

To answer your question, you can make use of the [TvLazyRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/tv/foundation/lazy/list/package-summary#TvLazyRow(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.tv.foundation.lazy.list.TvLazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.tv.foundation.PivotOffsets,kotlin.Function1)) composable to build a lazy row compatible with TV. To keep the focus at the same position, you can make use of the `pivotOffset` ([PivotOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/tv/foundation/PivotOffsets)) param of [TvLazyRow](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/tv/foundation/lazy/list/package-summary#TvLazyRow(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.tv.foundation.lazy.list.TvLazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.tv.foundation.PivotOffsets,kotlin.Function1)) to position the items inside of the row at a fixed position.

Comment: thanks, saved me a lot of time! compose tv docs is still too complex for me to understand

Comment: @Firate It would be really great if you could [create a new ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1254578&template=1739419) and mention what things did you find complex to understand. Was the API reference too complex or maybe the [introduction codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/compose-for-tv-introduction) was complex to understand. It will be more actionable to know what exactly is complex.